# Netboot Image - Where is the user generated data stored

Tags: macos, osx-server, netboot

I have a OS X Lion Server hosting netboot images. I also have a 10.8 Server for creating 10.8 images, but am hosting all images from one 10.7 NetBoot server.

When a client machine boots a specific net boot image, my understanding is that it copies at least the most necessary parts of the image via network and stores it somehow on its local resources.

Does it only store the data in the RAM or does it save data locally?

Where is newly generated session data stored? On the Server or locally ?

Comment: What versions of Server? What OS is the client? How did you prepare the net boot image? Much depends on the options you chose when creating the image.

Comment: Mac OS 10.7.5 server, Clients 10.7.5 and 10.8.3. I prepared the netboot image using the System image Utility. No specific options on creation.

Comment: I'll try to make an effort to answer, but the user generated data is stored in the user's home folder. You can control this on a per server basis, per user basis or per machine basis or a mix of any of the above. (also - I edited your question to incorporate the text, please review it as I'm not sure I yet understand your main intent here or what you do and don't get about NetBoot currently)

Answer (score 5):

When you NetBoot, the read-only NetBoot DMG file gets mounted read-write via the use of a *Shadow File*. Any Mac OS X DMG file can be mounted with a Shadow file. When a Shadow file is in use, any data which would be written to the DMG file is instead written to the Shadow file, and when data is read, the data will be read from the Shadow file first before the DMG file.

When NetBooting, there are three kinds of images, each with three different methods of mounting the DMG and storing the Shadow file:

- **NetInstall Images** are made from a Mac OS X Installer DVD or an Installer Image downloaded from the App Store. They have no Shadow file, the root partition `/` is read only and there is no swap.
- **NetBoot Images** are made using System Image Utility from an installed Mac OS X system. the Shadow file is stored on the first hard disk in the hidden `/private/netboot` folder
- **Diskless Netboot Images** are the same as **NetBoot Images** but the Shadow file is stored over the network using Apple File Protocol (AFP)

In the case of **Diskless Netboot** (The most powerful), the Shadow file is stored in the `NetBootClients0` folder of the `Library/NetBoot` folder on the server machine (Or `NetBootClients1`, NetBootClients2`, etc, where the number matches the number of the`NetBootSP` folder in which the Net Boot DMG resides)

To make a NetBoot image a **Diskless Netboot Image**, use the "Make this image available for Diskless booting" checkbox under the image settings in **Server.app**:

[image: Screenshot of image settings]

You also need to have AFP File Sharing enabled, and you need a guest writable sharepoint for the NetBoot directory. (I do not recall if Server.app creates this automatically) [Apple has a document about troubleshooting Diskless NetBoot](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4316) which is helpful. [AFP548 also has some great hints](http://afp548.com/static/mactips/netboot.html)

> When a client machine boots a specific net boot image, my understanding is that it copies at least the most necessary parts of the image via network and stores it somehow on its local resources

This is not technically correct. When you NetBoot, the Mac OS X Kernel mounts the root filesystem (`/`, the boot volume) *over the network*. So nothing is stored locally. When data needs to be read (E.G. an application is launched) it is read over the network, rather than from your hard drive. No data is copied from the server to the local machine.

When *changes are made*, for example, a new file is saved, then the Mac OS X kernel needs to write those changes somewhere, and that's where the Shadow file comes in. As described above the Shadow file might be on the first local hard drive, but it might also be stored over the network. If it is stored over the network, then the Mac OS X client can actually unmount the drives and do things like running Disk Utility. It can even have the hard drives completely removed.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the NetBoot image is a read-only asset, so each client downloads enough of the image to boot.

During boot, the OS Client makes a shadow file for local storage and changes.

Those changes can be re-used the next time that Mac boots from the network. If the shadow file gets deleted, the boot process will re-create it if needed.

This only will be of use for describing the initial boot assets and changes made to the core system. You will also want to think through how user changes are being mounted, stored, captured and backed up.

Netboot is great for troubleshooting and initial loading of an installer image. I've also seen it for loading a diagnostics suite or kiosk situations  when you simply start up a single app where all the data on a server or cloud and no real data lies ever on the client (think museums or digital signage). I suppose a motivated team could engineer a total solution where all the Macs net boot, but it's usually better to let each Mac run it's own OS and have other methods to audit, control, re-image things when needed.

Comment: I am motivated and have engineered a system whereby everybody netboots. Their users are in open Directory and their home directories are stored on a fileserver, so that storage is persistent. But every reboot resets the system software and the installed applications (under `/Applications`) to the default. I find it cheaper and more reliable than other solutions for backup and re-imaging.